# Can you get rid of the ZeroAccess botnet without a complete reinstall?

Tags: botnet, virus-removal

I'm interested in the recommended course of action for when you find a (Windows) system infected with the ZeroAccess botnet.

I've seen various blog posts online recommending that the user download and run a script, which will remove the botnet, but in your opinion is this enough, or is a full re-install recommended?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Some [background](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/09/blood-sucking-botnet-narrowly-escapes-extermination-lives-to-leech-again/): The Zeroaccess rootkit/botnet is a multi-purpose, highly resilient bit of malware. It causes compromised devices to participate in [click-fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_fraud) and [mine Bitcoins](http://techcrunch.com/2013/04/08/how-to-mine-bitcoins/). Compromised devices participate in a [peer-to-peer Command and Control network](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/grappling-zeroaccess-botnet), which makes the botnet resilient against takedown measures.

Overall, it is a very clever bit of malware that is [still being investigated in detail](http://www.virusbtn.com/conference/vb2013/abstracts/LM5-GibbThakur.xml):

> Ross Gibb and Vikram Thakur will be presenting their findings from
>   this operation at the annual Virus Bulletin Conference to be held in
>   Berlin, October 2-4, 2013. In addition, a comprehensive white paper
>   will be released soon to coincide with the presentation laying out the
>   inner details of the ZeroAccess threat.

Given how well-written this malware is, the usual recommendation applies - **the only way to be certain is to rebuild the device from known good media**.

If this machine is one you use regularly, then you should strongly consider rebuilding it ("rebuild" here means to reinstall or restore your Operating System to factory defaults).

If you *must* give up some security in order to save time or money, then there are some removal tools out there from reputable vendors: [Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2011-121607-4952-99), [AVG](http://free.avg.com/us-en/remove-win32-zeroacces), [ESET](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2895), [McAfee](http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/how-to-use-rootkitremover.aspx) to name a few.

Perhaps if the infected computer is only used by your 8 year old nephew to play Angry Birds, you could consider just using a removal tool or process.